# What is the distance limit of Google Places API?

Tags: android, google-places-api

Google places api is used to find business location near to the current location. What is the distance limit for that? I can't find some places far from the current location. Its possible to find near locations.

Comment: can you elaborate more your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`radius` — Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return place results. The maximum allowed `radius` is 50 000 meters.

Answer (score 9):

[The places API documentation for a place search request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) says...

"The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters"

Don't know why nobody else has answered with this. Maybe that was added to the docs recently.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Google Places API for some time now and I've found the radius distance limit to be 100 miles (expressed in meters).  After this, I get INVALID_RESULT.